# brew install mongo is not working in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, homebrew

Unable to install mongo in ubuntu:

[image]

Comment: Follow this instructions instead of using brew: [Install MongoDB Community Edition on Ubuntu](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

use below documents to install on ubuntu.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/